# How to cancel node creation in case a property value is wrong, via behaviour?

Tags: java, alfresco, behavior

One the one hand, I know how to check properties of the node in `NodeService.OnCreateNodePolicy`, because it gets a child association of newly created node as a parameter, but at this time the node is already created, so I just can remove it.

And on the other hand, I think that theoretically, I can prevent the node creation in `NodeService.BeforeCreateNodePolicy`, but I can't check the node properties, because it does not exist yet!

So is there any way to avoid "delete on create" solution?

Comment: What happens if you throw a suitable exception from the OnCreate policy? eg `AlfrescoRuntimeException`

Comment: @Gagravarr Didn't work for me, because the node seems to be already created (see my comment for the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, you can throw an exception and the transaction will be rolled back.

If this is acceptable, it depends on your use case.

Sometimes it can be better to listen for updates of the properties on "every event". If this is feasible depends again on your use case. If, for example, you know that you are setting all the properties in the same time or if you know that one property will be always set at the end, you can wait for that property and check the constraints on all the others.
The advantage of using "every event" is that the exception eventually thrown can be "managed" because the control will return to the code that was trying to save the node.

Comment: I've tried this, but for some reasons it didn't roll back. I used `TRANSACTION_COMMIT` frequency. And as the documentation in `NodeServicePolicies` says about `OnCreateNodePolicy`:
Called when a new node has been created.

Comment: Mmm... strange. It cannot commit the transaction if there was an uncaught exception.

Comment: But may be transaction already commited at this point? Or i'm doing something wrong...

Comment: If you throw an unchecked exception, Alfresco will not catch it and Spring will rollback the transaction. I do not know what transaction your code throws, but because the method onCreateNode does not throw checked exceptions, your code is necessarily throwing an unchecked exception and so... the transaction should be rolled back. But if you say that this is not the case, I believe you and I could be missing something. Having said that, I would suggest to try again just to be sure that there wasn't something wrong when you tried.

Comment: Yeah, something was wrong, but we'll newer know what) I wrote all from scratch, and it works.
And the exception WAS throwing in the wrong code... but node was created too.. strange.